# Queues do not start laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

php artisan queue:work - don't work.
ErrorException: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/QueueManager.php:156

```
protected function resolve($name)
     {
       $config = $this->getConfig($name);

      return $this->getConnector($config['driver'])
                         ->connect($config)
                       ->setConnectionName($name);
    }
```

config/queue.php

```
<?php

return [


    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),


    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],


        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ]
];
```

Comment: What is your `QUEUE_CONNECTION` in your `.env` file?

Comment: QUEUE_CONNECTION=databes

Comment: It should be `QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`. If your using a custom connection, the `driver` key must be defined in `config/queue.php`.

Comment: I showed the code queue. I don't quite understand what I need to fix?

Comment: Your `config/queue.php` is correct. The value of `QUEUE_CONNECTION` on your `.env` is wrong. It should be `database` not `databes`.

Comment: yes, I noticed) thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned above, this error can be caused by mis-configurations so try:

- check your `.env` file for the proper `QUEUE_CONNECTION`.
- add the connection name to your work command e.g `php artisan queue:work database --queue=queue_name` to run on `database` connection

In my case however, I ran into this error when using supervisor on a production server. The supervisor process failed with that error but for a newly created configuration. I had a configuration that was already running perfectly so I ended up copying the working configuration and editing it and it worked. I suspect was copying incorrectly formatted text because I pre-created the configurations locally on a text file.